# Не работает .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Разрабатываю не в VS, а в SharpDevelop, хочу сделать простое ASP.NET MVC приложение мне пишет, не выбран URL проекта, пошел в настройки там пишет **Local IIS IIS express was not found** и URL я установить не могу
у меня установлен денвер, это может повлиять?
Подскажите как быть, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

На apache можно, но с настройками морока. [Пример](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2779/Cassini-and-Apache-101) настройки (через Cassini сервер). Но судя по комментам у многих не получается. Проще поставить IIS Express или Cassini.